# Remove pressed key from vim input buffer

Tags: c++, c, vim

I'm writing a vim auto-command for cpp files where I want an abbreviation for **`#include`** lines.

The goal is for the abbreviation to expand to **`#include <`**▐**`>`** with the pipe being the location of the cursor after expansion.

Since naturally the abbreviation is to be followed by a space I'm trying to remove the input space from the register and move on.
However even after exiting insert mode and returning, or any trick I could think of: deleting next key, keying in bs etc, the space is being entered after whatever series of commands the iabbrev includes.

Therefore I'm looking for something that will remove the space from the register AND put me still in insert mode.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
   autocmd FileType cpp iab <buffer> #i #include <><Left><C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<CR>

   func Eatchar(pat)
      let c = nr2char(getchar(0))
      return (c =~ a:pat) ? '' : c
   endfunc
```

Answer (score 0):

In [lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp), I have in a C ftplugin (the place where such definitions should be)

```
iab  <buffer> #n    <C-R>=lh#map#no_context("#n ",'\<esc\>0i#include')<CR>
:Brackets < > -open=function('lh#cpp#brackets#lt') -visual=0
```

With `lh#map#no_context()` that prevents the expansion of `#n` within string and comment contexts -- sometimes, we want to be able to type `auto s = "#n";`, and `lh#cpp#brackets#lt` that recognizes a few contexts in which I can expand my `<` into `<>` (includes, templates, castings, etc).

As you see I don't automatically append `""` nor `<>` here as I want to be able to choose between `#include <foo>` and `#include "foo"`

Back to abbreviations that don't eat the space characters, the answer is in the help, see Menix's answer.

To simplify my task, I've defined a command that automatically applies such function (in [lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/) this time):

```
command! -narg=+ Iabbr execute "iabbr " <q-args>."<C-R>=lh#map#eat_char('\\s')<CR>"
command! -narg=+ Inoreabbr
      \ execute "inoreabbr " <q-args>."<C-R>=lh#map#eat_char('\\s')<CR>"
```

Thus, I would define your abbreviation this way

```
:Inoreabbr <silent> <buffer> #n< #include <><left>
:Inoreabbr <silent> <buffer> #n" #include ""<left>
```

Or even better to not see these abbreviations triggerred in string and comment contexts:

```
:Inoreab  <buffer> <silent> #n<    <C-R>=lh#map#no_context("#n< ",'\<esc\>0i#include <>\<left\>')<CR>
" and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from @LucHermitte's answer (and the similar attempt by @Meninx before), eating that character is a bit involved.

Instead, I would recommend you upgrade to a *snippets plugin* (if you don't use one already). *Snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).

Depending on the snippet plugin, the expansion may need to be explicitly triggered, others may already support insertion without the trailing space. Usually, you can configure a default for the included filename (that can be overwritten easily) - this functionality cannot be had via Vim abbreviations alone.

#### alternative

If you don't want full snippets functionality just for this, I would recommend to define the abbreviation based on triggering it with `<Enter>` instead of `<Space>`. This should fit well for this example (the next code / `#include` will be on a new line, anyway), and so you don't have to artificially remove anything.

Comment: The only things that we cannot have with abbreviations alone are: - something simple to maintain (see my context sensitive abbreviations), - and the ability to trigger the expansion from any number of characters typed (`i`, `incl`, etc). I've tried to explain the difference between both worlds [on vi.SE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30279618/15934). IOW, we definitively can have placeholders with abbreviations. Do we want to maintain them? Probably not.

Comment: @LucHermitte With placeholders, I was explicitly thinking of snipMate's `${1:placeholder1} in ${2:text2}`; you'd need some mappings to jump between them, so strictly not just abbreviations. Also, for mirroring, some `autocmd CursorMovedI` is necessary. In general, I agree with your linked answer: Use abbreviations for simple stuff, and snippets for the advanced stuff.

Comment: Indeed we need some mappings. As, I've been providing them for a very long time (2002 it seems) along with the utility functions to define context sensitive abbreviations and mappings, I tend to consider advanced abbreviations and placeholders support to belong to the same category. Regarding mirroring, I cheat and rely on Tom Link's stakeholders plugin which is compatible with "my" old placeholder framework.